# global variable in class php

Tags: php, variables

I want to use a variable as global in a recursive function defined in a class. I want something like this.

```
<?php
  class copycontroller extends BaseController {
    function copycontroller () {
      $foo="123" ;
      function recursive () {
        global $foo ;
        echo $foo ;
        recursive() ;
      }
      recursive();
   }
}
```

in my origin code I have a condition for stop recursive.output is `NULL`. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Where is the logic which stops the recursion?  I don't see anything there.

Comment: I do not put that logic in here.

Comment: Why you can't pass parameter to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest functions like that. You can do something like this:

```
class copycontroller extends BaseController {
    function copycontroller() {
        $foo="123";
        $this->recursive();
    }

    function recursive() {
        global $foo;
        echo $foo;
        $this->recursive()
    }
}
```

Also notice that using global variables is considered bad practice. I'm not sure what your goal is, but it may be better to define class property `$foo`, and access it instead:

```
class copycontroller extends BaseController {
    protected $foo;

    function copycontroller() {
        $this->foo = "123";
        $this->recursive();
    }

    function recursive() {
        echo $this->foo;
        $this->recursive()
    }
}
```